# Which of these folders inside of the Media folder do not need to be migrated from Magento 1 to Magento 2?

Tags: product-images, migration, media-images

```
Magento 1.9.4 --> Magento 2.4.2-p1
```

I have done the settings and data migration by using the Magento Migration Tool. I am now using FTP to download all folders and subfolders in the MEDIA directory on Magento 1 with the plan of re-uploading this to the MEDIA folder in Magento 2. Looking at the subdirectories of my Magento1/public_html/media directory:

```
captcha
catalog 
css 
css_
secure 
customer 
dailydeal 
dhl 
downloadable
email 
favicon 
import 
js 
magpleasure 
porto 
smartwave 
tmp 
wysiwyg
xmlconnect 
.htaccess
```

*It seems that some of these folders have to do with the Porto theme which I will install and configure fresh for Magento 2 and also some extensions which again I will install specifically in their Magento 2 versions later.*

**Would someone be able to advise which of these subcategories can be skipped when re-uploading the Media folder via FTP to the new Magento 2?**

---

**ANSWER** on July 14th, 2021:

The following directories are Magento default folders which **need to be copied:**

```
 1. catalog
 2. customer
 3. dhl
 4. downloadable
 5. xmlconnect
```

*Do not copy the .htaccess!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above list, these are the magento default folder which you need to take.

```
 1. catalog
 2. customer
 3. dhl
 4. downloadable
 5. xmlconnect 
 6. .htaccess
```

All other are may be third party extension use or magento use.